# c# OleDbDataAdapter; occurrence number?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I've done little bits of database stuff in the past, including SQL (although I don't know which variations they were); in one of them I'm sure there was an 'occnum' keyword or similar, which allowed a row in a table without unique fields to be addressed by index?

In my current situation, a few years and an entirely different workplace later, I'm faced with writing a C# application that allows a company specific Access database to be edited. This database lacks primary keys, so I've tried to find a similar 'occurrence number' functionality to edit specific rows with and haven't found anything. Changing the database structure is not an option, and none of the fields are unique.

As an example, I use an OleDbDataAdapter to query some rows as follows:

```
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oleDBA = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand("SELECT " + FIELDNAME_ITEMDATA_TAG + " FROM " + TABLENAME_ITEMDATA + " WHERE " + FIELDNAME_ITEMDATA_AREANUMBER + " = " + Area.ToString(), oleDbConnection));
        oleDBA.Fill(dataSet, "ResourceString");

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result.Add(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
```

The string list is then used to populate a ListBox. When entries on the list box are populated, I would like to be able to query an individual row by it's occurrence number, something like:

```
"SELECT " + FIELDNAME_ITEMDATA_TAG + " FROM " + TABLENAME_ITEMDATA + " WHERE " + FIELDNAME_ITEMDATA_AREANUMBER + " = " + Area.ToString(), oleDbConnection AND OCCNUM = " + OccNum
```

Is this doable? Have I just failed to find the correct keyword?

Comment: You really, **really** want to parameterize those `OleDbCommand` queries.  Look at how to use `OleDbParameter`.

Comment: If there's not a unique column to use as a primary key, is there some _combination_ of columns that IS unique that you could use?

Answer (score 0):

`occnum` is an Oracle database function, it is not accessible through Access.

That said, IIRC, Access doesn't have any concept of a built-in primary key (which is really what you want).  You're going to have to add it yourself.

That said, you should add a primary key to your tables, and then select both the primary key and the tag name in the routine (you could name your primary keys the same across all of your tables if you are generating queries on-the-fly as you are above) and then query by the primary key when you want to get more information.

You should also figure out what the [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) is for each of the tables and make sure that you have a unique index on that (or, if you want, you *could* make that column the primary key, but I'd recommend against it).

Finally, if you create a primary key that is a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), then you can make it an auto-incrementing column, so that you don't have to worry about generating the key when you insert new values.